# Print the main menu in overridden node page

Tags: navigation

In development site. I am using sitemap page so i need to print the all main menu and submenu in that page. I am using this code, but it is not working.

```
$main_menu = menu_navigation_links('menu-main-page');
echo '<pre>main menu';print_r($main_menu);
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render the menu for sitemap purpose, better to use the "[Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/site_map)" module

Configuration page from this link

```
admin/config/search/sitemap
```

You can see the below screen on configuration page,

[image]

Just check the menu, which you want to display in sitemap.

After this you can access your page with `/sitemap` url and you can see your menu there on that page.

Answer (score 0):

if drupal 7 try this

```
 <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
    'links' => $main_menu,
 'attributes' => array(
     'id' => 'menu',
    ),
    'heading' => array(
  'text' => t('Main menu'),
     'level' => 'h2',
   'class' => array(
    'element-invisible',
       ),
     ),
     ));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works on Drupal 7.

```
$menu = menu_tree('main-menu');
$menuhtml = drupal_render($menu);
print_r($menuhtml);
```